# R- Fill columns in df

Tags: r, fill, col

In this data frame:

```
           a        b   c d e  f g
1         <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
2         <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
3          S        Sm  H W Ja C S
4          Ja       K   H W Ja C S
5         <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
6         <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
7         <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
8          H        M   H W Ja C S
9          C        Ja  H W Ja C S
10        <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
11        <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
12        <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
13        <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
14         W        H   H W Ja C S
15         K        J   H W Ja C S
16        <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
17        <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
18        <NA>     <NA> H W Ja C S
```

In every row I want to replace values in columns c:g that matches values in column a with values in column b. After every substitution I want to fill down values in the column untill there's another substitution.
It may sound complicated, but at the end it should look like this.

```
           a           b   c d e  f  g
1         <NA>        <NA> H W Ja C  S
2         <NA>        <NA> H W Ja C  S
3          S           Sm  H W Ja C  Sm
4          Ja          K   H W K  C  Sm
5         <NA>        <NA> H W K  C  Sm
6         <NA>        <NA> H W K  C  Sm
7         <NA>        <NA> H W K  C  Sm
8          H           M   M W K  C  Sm
9          C           Ja  M W K  Ja Sm
10        <NA>        <NA> M W K  Ja Sm
11        <NA>        <NA> M W K  Ja Sm
12        <NA>        <NA> M W K  Ja Sm
13        <NA>        <NA> M W K  Ja Sm
14         W           H   M H K  Ja Sm
15         K           J   M H J  Ja Sm
16        <NA>        <NA> M H J  Ja Sm
17        <NA>        <NA> M H J  Ja Sm
18        <NA>        <NA> M H J  Ja Sm
```

Data

```
structure(list(a = c(NA, NA, "S", "Ja", NA, NA, NA, "H", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, "W", "K", NA, NA, NA),
               b = c(NA, NA, "Sm", "K", NA, NA, NA, "M", "Ja", NA, NA, NA, NA, "H", "J", NA, NA, NA), 
               c = c("H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H"),
               d = c("W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"),
               e = c("Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja", "Ja"),
               f = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
               g = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S")),
          .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), class = "data.frame",
          row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```

Comment: It is not that clear.  Why you are filling the 'c' column with "M"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `for` loop:

```
x <- df[1,c('c','d','e','f','g')]
for (i in seq(nrow(df))) { 
    x[x==df[i,'a']] <- df[i,'b']
    df[i,c('c','d','e','f','g')] <- x
}
df
##       a    b c d  e  f  g
## 1  <NA> <NA> H W Ja  C  S
## 2  <NA> <NA> H W Ja  C  S
## 3     S   Sm H W Ja  C Sm
## 4    Ja    K H W  K  C Sm
## 5  <NA> <NA> H W  K  C Sm
## 6  <NA> <NA> H W  K  C Sm
## 7  <NA> <NA> H W  K  C Sm
## 8     H    M M W  K  C Sm
## 9     C   Ja M W  K Ja Sm
## 10 <NA> <NA> M W  K Ja Sm
## 11 <NA> <NA> M W  K Ja Sm
## 12 <NA> <NA> M W  K Ja Sm
## 13 <NA> <NA> M W  K Ja Sm
## 14    W    H M H  K Ja Sm
## 15    K    J M H  J Ja Sm
## 16 <NA> <NA> M H  J Ja Sm
## 17 <NA> <NA> M H  J Ja Sm
## 18 <NA> <NA> M H  J Ja Sm
```

This assumes a few things:

- All of the `df` columns are character (not factor)
- The initial value of each row is the same as the first row.